# Jenkins - "Not sending mail to unregistered user" whereas option "Allow sending to unregistered users" is activated

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

In the configuration of my Jenkins project, in the part "Post-build Actions" I have added an "E-mail Notification" action where I have put my email and checked the 2 boxes:

- Send e_mail for every unstable build
- Send separate e-mails to individuals who broke the build

But when a build failed after one of my commits on GitLab, I have got an error message and receive only one over the 2 emails I should receive:

```
Build step 'Run MATLAB Command' changed build result to FAILURE
Not sending mail to unregistered user julie.user@company.com
Sending e-mails to: julie.user@company.com
Finished: FAILURE
```

Worth to mention that the option "Allow sending to unregistered users" is activated in:
Manage Jenkins > System > Extended E-mail Notification

I have tried to register myself as an Jenkins user (I am currently logged as "admin") but it does not change anything.
I have also updated the plugin and Jenkins itself (I am now running the 2.414.2 version)  but nothing works...

I don't know how to configure Jenkins so the user responsible for the failure of the build is notified by email, without being notified at every failed build when it is not his/her fault.

My relevant Jenkins settings:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add all relevant text to the question instead of linking images.

Comment: @yacc Unfortunately I can not upload images, but I have done the modifications I could to avoid linking images

Comment: I've inlined the images to support your question and added the GitLab tag, please check if it looks right. It's ok to link images of course, if it contributes to clarity. I've also completed the error message.

Comment: @yacc Great! Thanks a lot for your help and corrections!